# Emacs org-mode markdown export: #+TITLE option not exported

Tags: emacs, export, markdown, org-mode

I use the great `org-mode` to easily push modifications of `README.md` to GitHub projects. Markdown export works great, except for the `#+TITLE` option not being exported to Markdown - which works flawlessly for HTML export.

I want to keep the file name `README.org` for convenient converting to Markdown, else I could have chosen the title as file name, which displays the title correctly on GitHub.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Where do you expect the `#+TITLE` to be displayed in a Markdown file?

Comment: As the 1st headline like in the html-export and as it is if I named the org file like the desired title.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that `#+TITLE` becomes a first headline in HTML. Wouldn't it make more sense to map `* Heading` to `<h1>`, `** Heading` to `<h2>`, etc., and `#+TITLE` to `<title>`? In any case, if you want a top-level heading in Markdown why don't you just use a top-level heading in Org?

Comment: This would indeed be an option, but I didn't figure out how to remove top-level headings from TOC and omit the paragraph number?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you need. It would help if you could to show a minimal example of what your Org file looks like, what the exported Markdown file looks like, and what needs to change.

Comment: @barrios Paragraph numbering can be turned off by including `#+OPTIONS: num:nil` at the top of your `.org` file (or globally by customizing the variable `org-export-with-section-numbers`). This is described [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html).

Comment: Here is my github-project (in german), title should be before TOC: https://github.com/barrio/raspi-emacs org version is also uploaded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your question and subsequent comments, you seem to want to achieve three things:

1. Define a custom title that gets exported as a top-level headline.
2. Insert the TOC *after* the title.
3. The TOC should not include the title.

---

### Custom location for TOC

Inserting the TOC at a custom location is easy, so let's start with that: Add

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
```

to the export options at the top of `README.org`. By itself, this tells `org-mode` not to include the default TOC when exporting. You can then place the TOC where you want it to go by inserting

```
#+TOC: headlines
```

at the desired location. (This [method](http://orgmode.org/manual/Table-of-contents.html) is not specific to Markdown export.)

---

### Custom title that doesn't show up in TOC

Defining a custom title that is not included in the TOC is a bit trickier, but the basic idea is to exclude the title from the TOC by *formatting it as a Markdown headline* instead of an `org` headline. As a first step, change `README.org` to look like this:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

# Emacs als Python-Power-Editor für den RasPi

#+TOC: headlines

* Wieso nur ausgerechnet Emacs???
...
```

Out of the box this won't yield the desired results because `org` will interpret the title as a comment and by default the Markdown exporter is configured to ignore comments. However, in order to change the default behavior you can

1. define a custom transcoder for comments in your `.emacs`:

   ```lisp
   (defun org-md-comment (comment contents info)
     "Transcode COMMENT object into Markdown format.
   CONTENTS is nil.  INFO is a plist holding contextual information."
     (format "# %s" (org-element-property :value comment)))
   ```
2. redefine the Markdown export backend to make use of this transcoder:

   ```lisp
   (org-export-define-derived-backend 'md 'html
     ;; ...
     :translate-alist '((bold . org-md-bold)
                        (code . org-md-verbatim)
                        (comment . org-md-comment) ;; <--- Use custom transcoder
                        (comment-block . (lambda (&rest args) ""))
                        ;; ...
                        ))
   ```

   The original definition of the backend can be found in the file `ox-md.el`; this file is located in the directory of your `org-mode` installation. You'll need to copy the full definition to your `.emacs` file and change the line

   ```
   (comment . (lambda (&rest args) ""))
   ```

   as shown above.

---

### Results

With these customizations the resulting `README.md` file looks like this:

```
# Emacs als Python-Power-Editor für den RasPi

<div id="table-of-contents">
<h2>Table of Contents</h2>
<div id="text-table-of-contents">
<ul>
<li><a href="#sec-1">1. Wieso nur ausgerechnet Emacs???</a></li>
<li><a href="#sec-2">2. Die Maus ist tot, es leben die shortcuts!</a></li>
<li><a href="#sec-3">3. Auf den Emacs, fertig, los!</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

# Wieso nur ausgerechnet Emacs???
...
```

Comment: Brilliant! TNX for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

See http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/82634.

The problem is supposed to be fixed. Only waiting for an update of the converter on GitHub site...

Answer (score 1):

This is useful to get what the answer expects but *I think it is not the right path* to resolve this question. Let me explain it

I think the issue is about **exporting options from org-mode to md** but I also want to keep my docs in org-mode and this hacks org-mode export option adding another line for title exporting to md headline 1 but not manages the whole thing.

What I expect and I guess this is the important issue is **to export orgmode to md properly**, I mean:

- the title from orgmode to md heading one (#) -as orgmode to html does.
- the heading one from orgmode (*) to md heading two (##)

If this issue is not about it I should open a new one :)

Best!

Answer (score 0):

A few year later...

But my solution to this problem, that I also just experienced, was to modify the function `org-md-inner-template` in `ox-md.el`. This was done by adding a few lines, mimicking what exists for the same purpose in `ox-html.el`. After that, regular markdown exports will include the title if `org-export-with-title` is not `nil`.

The following is the modified function that will allow the title (and subtitle) to be exported to markdown as a level 1 heading:

```lisp
(defun org-md-inner-template (contents info)
  "Return body of document after converting it to Markdown syntax.
CONTENTS is the transcoded contents string.  INFO is a plist
holding export options."
  ;; Make sure CONTENTS is separated from table of contents and
  ;; footnotes with at least a blank line.
  (concat
   ;; Potential title as lvl 1 heading
   (let ((title (and (plist-get info :with-title)
                     (plist-get info :title)))
         (subtitle (plist-get info :subtitle))
         (style (plist-get info :md-headline-style))
         (level 1))
     (when title
       (org-md--headline-title
        style
        level
        (format "%s%s"
            (org-export-data title info)
                (if subtitle
                    (format " - %s" (org-export-data subtitle info))
                  "")))))

   ;; Table of contents.
   (let ((depth (plist-get info :with-toc)))
     (when depth
       (concat (org-md--build-toc info (and (wholenump depth) depth)) "\n")))

   ;; Document contents.
   contents
   "\n"
   ;; Footnotes section.
   (org-md--footnote-section info)))
```